# Git in Visual Studio Team Services, Visual Studio 2012 Project - can't deploy from build

Tags: git, visual-studio, tfs, continuous-integration, azure-devops

Can commit and sync fine in Git, Visual Studio 2012 Express project (update 2).

When I queue a build (Team Services - it is unclear what to enter in 'solution to build' I have tried the full path to .sln file, project file

[image]

Typical Error (I've tried many values):

```
Exception Message: The project file 'C:\Users
ick\Documents\Visual Studio 2012\Projects\myproject\myproject.csproj' was not found. (type FileNotFoundException)
Exception Stack Trace:    at System.Activities.Statements.Throw.Execute(CodeActivityContext context)
   at System.Activities.CodeActivity.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager)
   at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)
 TF270003: Failed to copy. Ensure the source directory C:\a\bin exists and that you have the appropriate permissions.
```

Where on earth is it getting the path 'c:\a\bin' from?

Any ideas how I can get this working?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

As per [this guide](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/visualstudioalm/archive/2013/02/12/run-ci-builds-in-your-git-team-project.aspx):

Open your team project in your web browser.

[image]

Browse to the solution and then copy the path to your clipboard so that you can paste it into the Solution to build box of the build definition, shown above.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

You put the relative path to your solution file, in my case it is :

[image]

c:\a is the checkout path on the build agent.