# Git project failing to build on Team Foundation Service

Tags: git, azure-devops

I'm running VS2012.2 and are trying to build a simple hello world app on Team Foundation Service using a Git Team Project,  but the build fails with solution file not found error - I can't seem to find where the place its looking for the solution file is referenced

I have cloned to

```
c:\Sources\Acme** and the solution file is located here...

c:\Sources\Acme\Development\Trunk\Source\AcmeProduct\AcmeProduct.sln
```

In the build definition I see the field: 2.1 Solution to build. In which I enter

```
Development\Trunk\Source\AcmeProduct\AcmeProduct.sln
```

In the build log I get

```
The project file 'C:\a\src\Development\Trunk\Source\AcmeProduct\AcmeProduct.sln' 
was not found. (type FileNotFoundException)
```

I'm curious as to where the **c:\a** came from, this folder doesn't exist on my pc. This build definition is using the default GitTemplate.xaml

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Have a look at my answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831603/git-in-team-foundation-service-visual-studio-2012-project-cant-deploy-from-bu/17117012#17117012

Comment: Thanks - thats the answer