# How to fix the file not found exception on TFS git project build server on visualstudio.com

Tags: git, tfs

How to fix the file not found exception on TFS git project build server on visualstudio.com. I am using VS2013. After chatting with Microsoft support I also logged this issue in the relevant Microsoft site http://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/91c01c10-d307-412c-8e81-9ca7d13af1f4/how-to-fix-the-file-not-found-exception-on-tfs-git-project-build-server-on-visualstudiocom?forum=TFService

> Exception Message: (type FileNotFoundException) Exception Stack Trace: at Microsoft.TeamFoundation.Deployment.Workflow.Activities.TryFindProjectInSolution.Execute(CodeActivityContext context) at System.Activities.CodeActivity`1.InternalExecute(ActivityInstance instance, ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager) at System.Activities.Runtime.ActivityExecutor.ExecuteActivityWorkItem.ExecuteBody(ActivityExecutor executor, BookmarkManager bookmarkManager, Location resultLocation)

[image]

Comment: possible duplicate of [Git in Team Foundation Service Visual Studio 2012 Project - can't deploy from build](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16831603/git-in-team-foundation-service-visual-studio-2012-project-cant-deploy-from-bu)

Comment: I have a build on VSO that is supposed to be the continuous delivery for azure, and it has exactly the same exception...

Comment: Followed @Veedrac's link to the duplicate & it fixed my problem. I'd changed the .sln file name but had not updated the CI build definition.